# Ex. 43 "Learn Python The Hard Way" - method does not run

Tags: python

I'm getting started to create a simple app basing on the skeleton of the author of the book. I don't understand why in the code below the method `enter` of class `Start` doesn't run and method `enter` of class `The_end` runs instead. Could you explain it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sys import exit

class Engine(object):    

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('the_end')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        current_scene.enter()


class Scene(object):    

    def enter(self):
        print "not configured yet"
        exit(1)  


class Start(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "Enter your name: "
        name = raw_input(" ")

        print "Hi %s. How old are you?" % (name)
        age = raw_input( )

        if age < 18:
            print "Sorry %s... You're too young to play this game." % (name)
            return 'the_end'

        elif age >= 18:
            print "Excellent %s! We can continue! Press enter" % (name)
            raw_input()

        print """Ok %s... I can tell you that it's not a comfortable situation.
        You've lost your memory so here's what happend.
        Today you were eating breakfast on your terrace and suddenly some alien showed from nowhere.
        It has minimized you with its odd gun so now your size is like a match box - more or less.
        Furthermore, the alien has teleported you - you are in some unknown empty house.
        You have to get yourself out in order to come back home, find the alien
        and bring back your initial size.""" % (name)

        raw_input()


class The_end(Scene):
    print "you're dead"
    exit(1)


class Map(object):   

    scenes = {
    "start": Start(),
    "the_end": The_end(),
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)


a_map = Map("start")
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be executed as the very first thing when you run your program:

```
class The_end(Scene):
    print "you're dead"
    exit(1)
```

You likely want something like this:

```
class The_end(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "you're dead"
        exit(1)
```

Everything you define in the class level (for a class defined on module level) will be executed as soon as Python comes by these lines. This also happens when you import a module with class-level code.

Comment: Now it's totally clear, thank you!